# Grafana Alerting - query intersection

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

so I'm trying to perform an intersection between two queries in Grafana Alerting, namely I have:

- Query A: list of IDs
- Query B: list of other IDs

I want to trigger an alert only for the intersection of the IDs of A and B, but I can't seem to be able to do so. Any suggestions?

Example:

Result from A: [1,2,3,4]

Result from B: [1,5,8,3]

I would like to perform a third query C (or a condition) and get [1,3] (intersection of A and B).